# how to set custom background-color in angular2-tree

Tags: angular, jstree

I am new in angular 4 and trying to implement angular2-tree. But I am unable to find the way to set background-color of each node dynamically.
I am trying to pass "color" in out list of data. 
Please suggest me.
Below is the my code :

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-checkboxes',
  template: ` 
    <h3>tri-state checkboxes</h3>
    <tree-root
      #tree
      [nodes]="nodes"
      [options]="options">

      <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index"  >
      <div [contextMenu]="myContextMenu" [contextMenuSubject]="node" >
     {{ node.data.name }}&nbsp; &nbsp; 
      <input 
          type="checkbox"
          [indeterminate]="node.data.indeterminate"
          [checked]="node.data.checked"> 
          </div>
      </ng-template> 
    </tree-root>  
  `,
  styles: [
  ] 
})
// nodes that are used to bind the tree -- Class 
  nodes = [
    {
      name: 'root1',
      checked: true,
      color:this.getNextColor(1),
      actions:[{
        enabled: true,
        execute: (node: any): void => console.log(node),
        html: (node: any): string => `John custom: ${node.name}`,
        visible: true,
      }, {
        divider: true,
        visible: true,
      }, {
        enabled: true,
        execute: (item: any): void => console.log(item),
        html: (item: any): string => `John custom: ${item.name}`,
        visible: true,
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'root2',
      checked: true,
      color:this.getNextColor(2),
      children: [
        { name: 'child1', checked: true },
        { name: 'child2', checked: true, children: [
          { name: 'grandchild1', checked: true },
          { name: 'grandchild2', checked: true }
        ] }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ngStyle`,

```
<div [contextMenu]="myContextMenu" [contextMenuSubject]="node" [ngStyle]="{ 'color': node.data.color" } >
 {{ node.data.name }}&nbsp; &nbsp; 
   ...
```

Comment: I have tried [ngStyle]="{ 'color': node.color }" and [ngStyle]="{ 'color': node.data.color }" both. There is an error that says "node" is undefined

Comment: I wonder if it's `node` undefined or `node.data` undefined. Because seems to me your `node` is given here `let-node="node"`, try print node by `{{ node }} or {{ index }}`. Just to first make sure you can access the `node` and the `node` property, ex. `data`

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake.. Thanks for help. But it only change the color inner section instead of full node/row.

Comment: Try `[ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': node.data.color }"`. And if you don't mind, could you vote my answer. Thank you.

Comment: [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': node.data.color }" change background color of tree-node-content but I want to apply color on "tree-node-level-1 tree-node " section. can you please help me in this?

Comment: For that, you won't be able to figure out via `template` tag, because the author didn't allow you to customize it. However as long as the `css` class can tell, you can just use what you proposed, ex. `tree-node-level-1 tree-node.red { background-color: red }`. Now the question is how to pass `red` as class, try `[ngClass]="'red': node.color == '#red'". It's not easy to use color code any more.